# Как в telegram-bot проверить подписан ли человек

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Нужно, чтобы бот отвечал только подписчикам определенного канала, а неподписчикам отвечал только просьбой подписаться. Читал мануал не нашел там такой функции.

Comment: Нет там такой функциональности.

Comment: Интересно, мануал чего вы читали "в поисках этой функции"?

Answer (score 2):

Это реализуется методом [*getChatMember(chat_id, user_id)*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember), где:

- *chat_id* - id канала (*или группы, супергруппы*);
- *user_id* - id пользователя.

Если пользователь подписан на канал - метод возвращает объект [*ChatMember*](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatmember), содержащий все пользовательские данные. Соответственно, проверяйте пользователя этим методом и если метод не вернул успешный ответ, значит пользователь не подписан на канал.

Comment: А не знаете где-нибудь пример кода?

Comment: @AndronioSunrise https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html?#telegram.Bot.getChatMember

Comment: @Anatol почему-то этот метод в любом случае возвращает мне {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"} не зависимо от того, состоит ли пользователь в группе/группе или нет. Не подскажете, в чем может бы дело?

Comment: бот должен быть в админах у канала, с возможностью ДОБАВЛЯТЬ УЧАСТНИКОВ или что то подобное