# Как боту проверить, подал ли я заявку на канал?

Tags: python, telebot

Как написать код , для того , чтобы бот реагировал на того , кто подал заявку на канал ?

Comment: да в принципе как и любой другой код - открывается удобный вам IDE и пишите в нем код

Comment: Также советую вам выбрать удобное кресло для того, чтобы было приятно писать код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781602/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-telegram-bot-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA

Comment: гугл меня понял после 2 слов, и в результатах поиска очень много информации, вплоть до видео, поэтому призываю вас гуглить

Comment: @ИванИпатов, здесь запрещено посылать участников в гугл.

Comment: Я приложил хороший вариант решения проблемы выше

Comment: @ИванИпатов, и тем не менее. Так нельзя.